# Why is it not possible for me to stage my directory, using Git-Extensions?

Tags: git, version-control, git-extensions

I'd like to add a directory, containing quite some files, to my GIT repository, but I can't even stage it.

In GIT-Extensions, it looks as follows:

[image]

The "description" part looks as follows:

```
Submodule Module.Hubmaster Change

Commit: 6f66f7fbbb25a1263c50d44912e6152ce496df40 (dirty)
                    1 year ago (3/11/2022 8:29:07)
        <commit comment>

Type: Dirty

Status:
 D ".vs/Hubmaster/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"
 D ".vs/Hubmaster/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide"
 D ".vs/Hubmaster/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-shm"
 D ".vs/Hubmaster/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-wal"
 D ".vs/<Other>/v15/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"
 D ".vs/<Other>/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide"
 D ".vs/<Other>/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-shm"
 D ".vs/<Other>/v15/Server/sqlite3/storage.ide-wal"
 M Hubmaster.Server/Manager.Order.cs
 M Hubmaster.Server/Manager.cs
?? ".vs/Hubmaster/FileContentIndex/"
```

The actual directory looks completely different:

```
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster>dir /S /B
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.gitattributes
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.gitignore
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\Hubmaster
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\Hubmaster.sln
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\Hubmaster.Client
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\Hubmaster.Server
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\packages
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\config
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\description
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\HEAD
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\index
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\info
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\logs
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\ms-persist.xml
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\objects
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\refs
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\applypatch-msg.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\commit-msg.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\fsmonitor-watchman.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\post-update.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\pre-applypatch.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\pre-commit.sample
C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\.git\hooks\pre-merge-commit.sample
...
```

I don't understand the red icon.
I don't understand the meaning of `Type: Dirty`.
In the "description", I see some double question marks, I have no idea what they mean.

When I try to stage, nothing happens (which means, no error message I can look for).

Does anybody know why I can't stage my directory structure and how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance

P.s. I managed to see the GIT commandlog. It looks as follows:

```
2024-03-15T13:55:48.1775261+01:00   65  53608   UI  0   git ls-files -z --unmerged  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.4945930+01:00   216 71224       0   git --no-optional-locks -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none status --porcelain=2 -z --untracked-files C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.6504258+01:00   103 29512       0   git --no-optional-locks for-each-ref --format="%(objectname) %(refname)" refs/heads/    C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.6548717+01:00   100 71148   UI  1   git rev-parse --quiet --verify "MERGE_HEAD~0"   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.6549073+01:00   268 58092       0   git -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none status --porcelain=2 -z --untracked-files C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.7122186+01:00   113 71508       0   git --no-optional-locks -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -U1000000 -- "<Source_Directory>/Views/DagPlanning.xaml"   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.7600925+01:00   113 61332       0   git config --includes --get user.name   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.8265674+01:00   113 48836       0   git --no-optional-locks -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -U1000000 -- "<Source_Directory>/Views/KernOven.xaml"  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.8745418+01:00   110 57464       0   git config --includes --get user.email  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.9230847+01:00   163 62404       0   git -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -- "Module.Hubmaster"  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.9262994+01:00   172 69832       0   git -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -- "Module.SRM"    C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.9368712+01:00   110 58524   UI  0   git rev-parse --quiet --verify "HEAD~0" C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:48.9416363+01:00   119 32208       0   git --no-optional-locks -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -U1000000 -- "<Firm>.<Product>.Server/Manager.Database.cs" C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:49.0735768+01:00   95  73340       0   git --no-optional-locks -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -U1000000 -- "<Firm>.<Product>.Server/Manager.cs"  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:49.0895543+01:00   77  19112   UI  0   git ls-files -z --unmerged  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:51.5449237+01:00   62  72816   UI  0   git rev-parse --git-common-dir  C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:51.6111681+01:00   63  51884   UI  0   git -c log.showSignature=false log -z -1 --pretty=format:"%H%T%P%n%at%n%ct%n%aN%n%aE%n%cN%n%cE%n%B%nNotes:%n%N" 6f66f7fbbb25a1263c50d44912e6152ce496df40    C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:51.6779819+01:00   70  76076   UI  0   git -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none status -s C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:53.9325308+01:00   67  76104   UI  0   git update-index --add --stdin  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.0014657+01:00   62  39908   UI  0   git ls-files -z --unmerged  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.0689804+01:00   65  73840   UI  0   git rev-parse --quiet --verify "HEAD~0" C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.1362982+01:00   65  38924   UI  0   git -c color.ui=never -c diff.submodule=short -c diff.noprefix=false -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none -c core.safecrlf=false diff --find-renames --find-copies -z --name-status --cached  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.2085278+01:00   63  47184   UI  0   git rev-parse --quiet --verify "HEAD~0" C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.3483290+01:00   96  29396   UI  0   git rev-parse --git-common-dir  C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.4539714+01:00   128 62444   UI  0   git -c log.showSignature=false log -z -1 --pretty=format:"%H%T%P%n%at%n%ct%n%aN%n%aE%n%cN%n%cE%n%B%nNotes:%n%N" 6f66f7fbbb25a1263c50d44912e6152ce496df40    C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:54.5853882+01:00   71  62844   UI  0   git -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none status -s C:\<Directory>\Module.Hubmaster\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.0518293+01:00   77  48204   UI  0   git ls-files -z --unmerged  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.1841169+01:00   174 63932       0   git -c log.showSignature=false log -z --pretty=format:"%H%T%P%n%at%n%ct%n%aN%n%aE%n%cN%n%cE%n%B%nNotes:%n%N" --max-count=100000 --all --    C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.1841430+01:00   113 68500       0   git stash list -z --pretty=format:"%H%T%P%n%at%n%ct%n%aN%n%aE%n%cN%n%cE%n%gD%n%B"   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.1841452+01:00   118 75028       0   git --no-optional-locks for-each-ref --format="%(if)%(authordate)%(then)%(objectname) %(refname)%(else)%(*objectname) %(*refname)%(end)"    C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.1855492+01:00   110 20284   UI  0   git ls-files -z --unmerged  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.3026723+01:00   92  65232       0   git for-each-ref --format="%(push:track,nobracket)::%(upstream:track,nobracket)::%(push)::%(upstream)::%(refname:short)" refs/heads/    C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.3950906+01:00   89  72264       0   git remote -v   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.5020756+01:00   116 6628        0   git branch --contains d940df7b7b202cbdc0a493b762265f61b9f8c1dc  C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.5021014+01:00   118 22912       0   git branch --format="%(refname)" -a --merged d940df7b7b202cbdc0a493b762265f61b9f8c1dc   C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.6190098+01:00   106 71232       0   git tag --contains d940df7b7b202cbdc0a493b762265f61b9f8c1dc C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.6601392+01:00   225 65980       0   git -c diff.ignoreSubmodules=none status --porcelain=2 -z --untracked-files C:\<Directory>\
2024-03-15T13:55:58.7256828+01:00   85  62936       128 git describe --tags --first-parent --abbrev=40 d940df7b7b202cbdc0a493b762265f61b9f8c1dc C:\<Directory>\
```

Comment: The reason (of red icon and not able to stage) is that your 'Hubmaster' is a submodule (or is at list detected as it by GitExtensions). It should be because you already have a repository created in the directory. And normally you should open the submodule and stage and create commit from there (and then update and commit from the parent repo). Or you don't want that it is a submodule and so keep only the content.

Comment: Or maybe you just want to open the 'Hubmaster' folder in gitextensions instead of parent repo.